# I get wrong result when calculating weight

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT ProjInfo.ProjectN AS BS,
       ProjShipp.Parts,
       SUM(CASE
                WHEN DailyPaProd.FK_idNextProcess = 13
                 AND ProjInfo.FK_Status != 'VENDRE DES MATIERES PREMIERES' THEN ProjShipp.[Weight] * DailyPaProd.[Quantity]
                ELSE 0
           END) AS [weight fab],
       SUM(ProjShipp.[Weight] * ProjShipp.ShippingNavisionQty) AS [weight Shipp]
FROM ProjectShipping ProjShipp
     INNER JOIN ProjectInfo ProjInfo ON ProjInfo.id = ProjShipp.IdProject
     INNER JOIN DailyPaintProduction DailyPaProd ON DailyPaProd.FK_idPartShip = ProjShipp.id
WHERE ProjInfo.ProjectN = 'BS-00799'
GROUP BY ProjInfo.ProjectN,
         ProjShipp.Parts,
         ProjShipp.[Weight];
```

when I run it I get this result

[image]

All result are correct except for TA1 on weight Shipp column I'm supposed to get 2352 instead of 11760.Why i am getting this error ,and how to fix it
Thanks in advance.

Update  
ProjectShipping table  
[image]

ProjectInfo table  
[image]

DailyPaintProduction table  
[image]

Comment: I suspect you have a one-to-many (or even many-to-many) relationship and therefore you're summing the same row multiple times. Without sample data, we can't really tell you much more. if you do provide sample data (and expected results) as **formatted `text`** (not an image), or as DDL and DML statements, we'll be able to help you far more easily.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not figure out how to insert a table into question,I try to use this tool https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables but i failed

Answer (score -1):

This query worked for me

```
SELECT ProjInfo.ProjectN AS BS,
   ProjShipp.Parts,
    (Select SUM(ProjectShipping.[Weight]*DailyPaintProduction.[Quantity])
    from DailyPaintProduction
    Inner Join ProjectShipping  on ProjectShipping.id=DailyPaintProduction.FK_idPartShip 
    Inner Join ProjectInfo  on ProjectInfo.id=ProjectShipping.IdProject
    Where  DailyPaintProduction.FK_idPartShip=ProjShipp.id and
            FK_idNextProcess=13 and 
            ProjectInfo.FK_Status!='VENDRE DES MATIERES PREMIERES')AS 'weight fab',

    SUM(ProjShipp.[Weight]*ShippingNavisionQty)AS 'weight Shipp'

 From ProjectShipping ProjShipp

 Inner Join ProjectInfo ProjInfo on ProjInfo.id=ProjShipp.IdProject

 WHERE ProjInfo.ProjectN = 'BS-00799'
 GROUP BY ProjInfo.ProjectN,
     ProjShipp.Parts,
     ProjShipp.[Weight],
     ProjShipp.id
```

Comment: How is this an answer to your question?  Do not put additional question in answer section.

Comment: Sorry for that I updated my answer.And I will open another question.