# Column 'ProjectShipping.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I want to summarize the work that I start here:

[I get wrong result when calculating weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805923/i-get-wrong-result-when-calculating-weight/56811532#56811532)

to look like this

[image]

So I run this query

```
SELECT 
    ProjInfo.ProjectN AS BS,
    (SELECT SUM(ProjectShipping.[Weight] * DailyPaintProduction.[Quantity] )
     FROM DailyPaintProduction
     INNER JOIN ProjectShipping ON ProjectShipping.id = DailyPaintProduction.FK_idPartShip 
     INNER JOIN ProjectInfo ON ProjectInfo.id = ProjectShipping.IdProject
     WHERE DailyPaintProduction.FK_idPartShip = ProjShipp.id 
       AND FK_idNextProcess = 13 
       AND ProjectInfo.FK_Status != 'VENDRE DES MATIERES PREMIERES') AS 'weight fab',
    SUM(ProjShipp.[Weight]*ShippingNavisionQty) AS 'weight Shipp'
FROM
    ProjectShipping ProjShipp
INNER JOIN
    ProjectInfo ProjInfo ON ProjInfo.id = ProjShipp.IdProject
WHERE 
    ProjInfo.ProjectN = 'BS-00799'
GROUP BY 
    ProjInfo.ProjectN,
    --ProjShipp.id,
    ProjShipp.[Weight]
ORDER BY
    ProjInfo.ProjectN
```

but I get this error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Column 'ProjectShipping.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The problem that if I add `ProjShipp.id` to the `GROUP BY`, the problem is solved but then I do not get a summary query

Any help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you put group by projectShipping.id? is inner select? If it is, please remove external select, and make the question simple.

Comment: `ProjShipp.id` is part of your correlated sub-query, hence the error.

Comment: @ Alex Yes that is right but until now I do not figure how.

Comment: @ Tony Dong Yes that is right but if I remove  external select i do not get the correct result